# Internal Server Error and no error logs show a error

Tags: ckan

I installed Ckan 2.8.2. I start the application and it run. But if I click on groups, dataset or organization - I got a "internal server error".

I increase the log-level. I search in every logfile. I restart database before starting Ckan. I created the datastore, set permissions. 
I use tail -f to monitor postgres behavior. I looked the output over paster in the python virtual-env.

Expected result is no internal error, and I can read and upload datasets.
One time I could do it, and after that nothing works, only login, create user etc.

Here the Ckan config file:

```
[DEFAULT]

# WARNING: *THIS SETTING MUST BE SET TO FALSE ON A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT*
#debug = true

[server:main]
use = egg:Paste#http
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 5000

[app:main]
use = egg:ckan
full_stack = true
cache_dir = /tmp/%(ckan.site_id)s/
beaker.session.key = ckan

# This is the secret token that the beaker library uses to hash the cookie sent
# to the client. `paster make-config` generates a unique value for this each
# time it generates a config file.
beaker.session.secret = BbMsj+g52f3rb72NrsGp3sFLh

# `paster make-config` generates a unique value for this each time it generates
# a config file.
app_instance_uuid = 60fbd1aa-28fb-4813-8521-6013b7b6edce

# repoze.who config
who.config_file = %(here)s/who.ini
who.log_level = warning
who.log_file = %(cache_dir)s/who_log.ini
# Session timeout (user logged out after period of inactivity, in seconds).
# Inactive by default, so the session doesn't expire.
# who.timeout = 86400

## Database Settings
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:#####@localhost/ckan_default

ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:#####@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:######@localhost/datastore_default

# PostgreSQL' full-text search parameters
ckan.datastore.default_fts_lang = english
ckan.datastore.default_fts_index_method = gist
```

### Site Settings

```
ckan.site_url = http://localhost:5000
ckan.use_pylons_response_cleanup_middleware = true

## Authorization Settings

ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_unowned_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_dataset_if_not_in_organization = false
ckan.auth.user_create_groups = false
ckan.auth.user_create_organizations = false
ckan.auth.user_delete_groups = true
ckan.auth.user_delete_organizations = true
ckan.auth.create_user_via_api = false
ckan.auth.create_user_via_web = true
ckan.auth.roles_that_cascade_to_sub_groups = admin


## Search Settings

ckan.site_id = default
solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/ckan

## Redis Settings

# URL to your Redis instance, including the database to be used.
ckan.redis.url = redis://localhost:6379/0


## CORS Settings

# If cors.origin_allow_all is true, all origins are allowed.
# If false, the cors.origin_whitelist is used.
# ckan.cors.origin_allow_all = true
# cors.origin_whitelist is a space separated list of allowed domains.
# ckan.cors.origin_whitelist = http://example1.com http://example2.com


## Plugins Settings

# Note: Add ``datastore`` to enable the CKAN DataStore
#       Add ``datapusher`` to enable DataPusher
#       Add ``resource_proxy`` to enable resorce proxying and get around the
#       same origin policy
ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view

# Define which views should be created by default
# (plugins must be loaded in ckan.plugins)
ckan.views.default_views = image_view text_view recline_view

# Customize which text formats the text_view plugin will show
#ckan.preview.json_formats = json
#ckan.preview.xml_formats = xml rdf rdf+xml owl+xml atom rss
#ckan.preview.text_formats = text plain text/plain

# Customize which image formats the image_view plugin will show
#ckan.preview.image_formats = png jpeg jpg gif

## Front-End Settings

# Uncomment following configuration to enable using of Bootstrap 2
#ckan.base_public_folder = public-bs2
#ckan.base_templates_folder = templates-bs2

ckan.site_title = test
ckan.site_logo = /base/images/ckan-logo.png
ckan.site_description =
ckan.favicon = /base/images/ckan.ico
ckan.gravatar_default = identicon
ckan.preview.direct = png jpg gif
ckan.preview.loadable = html htm rdf+xml owl+xml xml n3 n-triples turtle plain atom csv tsv rss txt json
ckan.display_timezone = server

# package_hide_extras = for_search_index_only
#package_edit_return_url = http://another.frontend/dataset/<NAME>
#package_new_return_url = http://another.frontend/dataset/<NAME>
#ckan.recaptcha.publickey =
#ckan.recaptcha.privatekey =
#licenses_group_url = http://licenses.opendefinition.org/licenses/groups/ckan.json

# ckan.template_footer_end =


## Internationalisation Settings
ckan.locale_default = en
ckan.locale_order = en pt_BR ja it cs_CZ ca es fr el sv sr sr@latin no sk fi ru de pl nl bg ko_KR hu sa sl lv
ckan.locales_offered =
ckan.locales_filtered_out = en_GB

## Feeds Settings

ckan.feeds.authority_name =
ckan.feeds.date =
ckan.feeds.author_name =
ckan.feeds.author_link =

## Storage Settings

ckan.storage_path = /var/lib/ckan
ckan.max_resource_size = 10
ckan.max_image_size = 2

## Datapusher settings

# Make sure you have set up the DataStore

ckan.datapusher.formats = csv xls xlsx tsv application/csv application/vnd.ms-excel application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
ckan.datapusher.url = http://127.0.0.1:8800/
#ckan.datapusher.assume_task_stale_after = 3600

# Resource Proxy settings
# Preview size limit, default: 1MB
#ckan.resource_proxy.max_file_size = 1048576
# Size of chunks to read/write.
#ckan.resource_proxy.chunk_size = 4096

## Activity Streams Settings

#ckan.activity_streams_enabled = true
#ckan.activity_list_limit = 31
#ckan.activity_streams_email_notifications = true
#ckan.email_notifications_since = 2 days
ckan.hide_activity_from_users = %(ckan.site_id)s


## Email settings

#email_to = errors@example.com
#error_email_from = ckan-errors@example.com
#smtp.server = localhost
#smtp.starttls = False
#smtp.user = username@example.com
#smtp.password = your_password
#smtp.mail_from =

## Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root, ckan, ckanext

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = DEBUG
handlers = console

[logger_ckan]
level = DEBUG
handlers = console
qualname = ckan
propagate = 0

[logger_ckanext]
level = DEBUG
handlers = console
qualname = ckanext
propagate = 0

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
```

Comment: Which installation instructions did you follow? Is Solr running and setup/connected properly?

Comment: Yes, what's your config's `solr_url`? I expect it is like: `http://localhost:8983/solr/`. Now try `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/` and see if it looks like a working web page or is an error you can debug. Also, be specific about what CKAN install and deployment you did and which log files you are looking in.

Comment: I follow 2.9 Source Installation.

Comment: I can call ckan solr, no problems. Solr Core Ckan is installed.